# Hidden button above div

Tags: c#, html, css, button, z-index

My goal is to hide a transparent button above a div element. When a user clicks the button, properties of the underlying div should be changed **using code in a C# click event**, not client-based code.

- The code below provides an example of changing a div's color properties, but my actual application modifies different properties.
- The button is clickable when positioned beside the div, but not when hidden above it (I tried using z-index).
- I understand that using JQuery or a dedicated CSS class is recommended above overwriting CSS styles, but I am required to use this approach.

Are there any additional CSS properties that could make the hidden button clickable?

**CSS:**

```
#container {
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:auto;
}

#MyHiddenButton {
    float:left;
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
    z-index:2;
    background-color:transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
}

#myContent {
    position:absolute;
    float:left;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    background-color:lightslategrey;
    z-index:1;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="myContent" runat="server"></div>
    <asp:Button ID="MyHiddenButton" runat="server" OnClick="MyHiddenButton_Click" />
</div>
```

**C# Code:**

```
protected void MyHiddenButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myContent.Style.Add("background-color", "red");
}
```

Comment: if you change the color server side, why not make not visible also the button ?

Comment: Changing the background-color style like that will make things difficult for you later. Inline styles override CSS and work against the typical separation of concerns found in the front end. I would recommend adding a class and handling the coloration in CSS instead.

Comment: @BDawg This simplifies a larger application, where clicking the button pings a database and changes the information contained in labels in the div.  The type of information delivered dictates the color.  Right now,  overriding the CSS is working without a problem when the button is located off the div.  I understand that there are other ways to handle the CSS restyling, but adding styles in C# is what is required in this situation.

Comment: @CharleyW. It still doesn't sound like that is what is required (a.k.a. the only way), but it's no big deal. You're more familiar with your problem than I am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly, a div isn't considered "clickable" in ASP, so you're trying to get a button to overlap and handle a click event in C#. If this is correct, you could handle the problem [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17875563/757839).

Also, I got it working using purely front end code like so:

```css
#container {
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}

#myHiddenButton {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    z-index: 2;
}

#myContent {
    position: absolute;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: lightslategrey;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="myContent"></div>
    <button id="myHiddenButton" onclick="alert('test');" />
</div>
```

*Note: I changed the one id to be consistent capitalization. You may need to change the id if you copy/paste any CSS (Don't mind my OCD)

Answer (score 0):

In this instance, I think you're better off controlling the display logic, including click areas with basic html elements, then using jquery on clicks to fire the event. Within that click you can then do a postback for the button. So the html would be something like this:

```
<script>
    $( "#myContent" ).click(function() {
       __doPostBack('<%= MyHiddenButton.ClientID %>', '')
    });
</script>

<div id="container">
    <div id="myContent" runat="server"></div>    
</div>
<asp:Button ID="MyHiddenButton" runat="server" OnClick="MyHiddenButton_Click" style="display:none" />
```

The button is hidden, so the event can still fire, but the div is the element that is firing the event. If you wanted just the top part of the div to be clickable you can create another div within it that is the click area.